# Alcohol in the bloodstream modeled by differential equations

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, reference-request, alcohols

Does anyone know any good references which use partial differential equations to model the alcohol concentration in the bloodstream? I'm a mathematician, so I'm searching for a rigorous mathematical model.

If you have any other suggestions of models in chemistry that uses partial differential equations, feel free to post them here.

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: "If you have any other suggestions of models in chemistry that uses partial differential equations, feel free to post them here." that is pretty broad... It covers about all physical chemistry with thermodynamics and quantum chemistry

Answer (score 1):

One such article that I found was published by the University of South Florida. The abstract for which reads:

> Given a set of differential equations describing blood alcohol content as a function time, we integrated the
>   equations to obtain a general solution. The general solution equation depends on three free parameters: the initial
>   concentration of alcohol in the stomach after ingestion, the rate of alcohol absorption into the blood stream and the rate
>   at which the alcohol is metabolized by the liver. We fitted our solution to experimental data to determine the unknown
>   parameters for a particular subject.

If this sounds useful to you, it can be found [here](http://scholarcommons.usf.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4819&context=ujmm).